# A page can have only one server-side Form tag.

Tags: asp.net, forms, master-pages

Masterpage.aspx

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js'>     
     </script>
     <script src="Chrome.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
     <form id="Master" runat="server">
      <table style="width:987px; margin:auto; height: 86px;">
       <tr style="background-color:#FFFFFF">
         <td class="style2">
           <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="" width="235" height="73" />&nbsp;
             </td>
             <td style="vertical-align:middle;"class="style1">
             <div style="float:right; width:153px; height: 22px;">
             &nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="20px" 
                                            style="margin-left: 0px" Width="140px">   
              </asp:TextBox>
              </div>
              <a href="">Forget Password?</a> </span></span>
               </td>
               <td class="style33">
              <div style="float:right; width:157px; height: 20px; margin-right: 1px;">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Height="20px"  
                                            style="margin-left: 0px; margin-top:  
                                            Width="147px"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </div>

              <a href="Registration.aspx">New User Registration</a> </span>
                                </td>
                                <td class="style40">
            <div style="height: 67px; width: 81px;">
            &nbsp<asp:Button ID="btnlogin" runat="server" style="color:White;  background-color:#404040;font-family:Verdana;font-size:10pt; height: 29px; margin-top: 12px;" Text="Login" onclick="btnlogin_Click1" /></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="background-color:#207DA8">
                    <td class="style39">
                    </td>
                    <td class="style39">
                    </td>
                </tr>



        <script type="text/javascript">

            cssdropdown.startchrome("chromemenu")

          </script>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                                        <img alt="" src="images/rgt.jpg" style="width: 471px; height: 247px" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr style="vertical-align=top;background-color=#D4D3D9">
                                    <td style="height:1;">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                         </tbody>
                         </table>
       <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
   </form>  
  </body>
  </html>
```

RegisterPage.aspx

```
  <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Registration.aspx.cs" ValidateRequest="false" Inherits="Paragraphreader.Registration" %>
  <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
   <script src="jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="jquery.validation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    $("#Register").submit(function () {
        return $(this).validation();
        alert("submitted");
    });

 </script>
 <script>
     function validate() {

         var a = 0, rdbtn = document.getElementsByName("gender");
         for (i = 0; i < rdbtn.length; i++) {
             if (rdbtn.item(i).checked == false) {
                 a++;
             }
         }

         if (a == rdbtn.length) {
             document.getElementById("RadioButtonList1").style.border = "2px solid red";
             return false;
         } else {
             document.getElementById("RadioButtonList1").style.border = "";
             return true;
         }

     }

 </script>

   <link href="Career.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <link href="Chrome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <link href="Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <form id="Register" runat="server">//A page can have only one form tag
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
  </asp:ScriptManager>
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="FormUpdatePanel" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>
```

I am getting error(A page can have only one server side cof while compiling RegisterPage.aspx.In the master page i have a form tag and server side code 
In the Register page i have a form tag and server side code.how to avoid this error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Master pages should not contain `form` tags in general because they are meant to be used only as the base layout of your content page. Remove the `form` tag from the Master page and the error will go away.

If you want to define a common "Login" section for all your pages (this appears to be your intent), you can instead create a `UserControl` to do this. You would then define a section inside your Master page to contain this user control making sure that the ContentPlaceHolder of the Login UserControl always ends up enclosed inside the content page's `form`. That way, when you submit the form, the `btnlogin_Click1` click event is triggered.

In conclusion: re-arrange your page in a way that you have one `form` tag per page, since ASP.NET does not allow having more than one and try to define your form's inside the content pages and not the Master page.

Comment: why we need only one?

Comment: @lmad one may need more than one `form` but ASP.NET will throw an error whenever you do it if they are server-side forms; in other words, if you have more than one `<form id="xyz" runat="server" ../>` when the page is rendered, you'll get an exception. You can create several forms in the page as long as they don't have the attribute `runat="server"` set. This is a restriction of the ASP.NET Framework itself.