# How to use a user control and master page for common login

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, master-pages

[See the code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480287/a-page-can-have-only-one-server-side-form-tag)

I want common login for all the pages using master pages.

Comment: just create a Usercontrol and add it to the master page - really simple

Comment: can you give the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a basic usercontrol and then drag it onto your master page.

Here is a simple example:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cvinodkumar/LoginUserControl11232005011130AM/LoginUserControl.aspx

Comment: can you give the example for master page