# asp.net error form cannot be nested within element form?

Tags: asp.net, forms

I have a content page in an asp.net application that uses a form tag. There's only one on the page so I'm confused why its give me the error: Validation (HTML5): Element 'form' must not be nested within element 'form'

Heres the code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication6._Default" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
   <div>
      <form id="form1">
         <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowPaging="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <Columns>
               <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
               <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
               <asp:BoundField DataField="Director" HeaderText="Director" SortExpression="Director" />
               <asp:BoundField DataField="DateReleased" HeaderText="DateReleased" SortExpression="DateReleased" />
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Selection">
                  <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:CheckBox ID="Selections" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged1" />
                  </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
         </asp:GridView>
         <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Movies]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
         <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Select Movies" OnClick="Button1_Click" CausesValidation="False" />
         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1"  Text="First Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
      </form>
   </div>
</asp:Content>
```

I have a form in my masterpage but that wasnt giving me problems yesterday..

Any ideas?

Comment: "I have a form in my masterpage but that wasnt giving me problems yesterday.." => is the content of the page rendered within the form on the masterpage?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" >` control is, itself, inside of a `form` element, then you shouldn't place a `form` inside of the `asp:content` control as you should not have nested forms.

From the [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/forms.html#the-form-element) working draft:

> 4.10.3 The form element
>   Content model:
>   Flow content, but with no form element descendants.

**UPDATE**

See the question [A page can have only one server-side Form tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15480367/1366033):

> Master pages should not contain form tags in general because they are meant to be used only as the base layout of your content page.

Try to restructure your project using these guidelines:

- Only add `form` elements to aspx pages
- Add main content to `MasterPage` from pages
- Add any content that needs to be nested within a form to a `UserControl` that is placed within a page.

Comment: Thanks that solved that issue! I placed the placeholder outside my MasterPage's form. But now I'm getting this error with my gridview..Control 'MainContent_GridView1' of type 'GridView' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server. And if i try to place runat="server" inside my form1 tag it complains that I can only have one form tag with runat="server" :/

Comment: I solved it. Didn't realize I could place put the placeholder inside the master page's form and then I wouldnt need a form in the content page.

Comment: @KyleMit : I have little different scenario. My master page have script manager which requires form tag with `runat=server` and my other page also have form tag which is conflicting with Master Page's form tag. Is there any option ?